# How to send checked checkboxes in request to server - automatically downloading file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, download

I wish to send checked checkboxes in request to server (for example, it's Django, in my case) and then, in response, automatically downloading file? I am interested in common recipes, advice or simple example. As I know, Ajax and JS(JQuery), in common, don't have a solution for it because of privacy. Or am I under a misapprehension?

My idea how to realize it:

HTML:

```
<a id="btn" href="#">Download</a>
...
<input class="select-row" type="checkbox" data-row-id="{{ item.id }}"/>
```

JS:

```
$( '#btn' ).on('click', function() {
        var checkedRows = [];
        $( '.select-row:checked' ).each(function() {
            checkedRows.push( $(this).data('row-id') );
        });
        $.ajax( {
            type: "POST",
            url: "/request/to/view/",
            data: {
                passed_rows: checkedRows,
            },
            async: false,
        } ).done( function() {
            console.log('The archive is downloaded.');
        } )
    });
```

Comment: hmm you could add an event to the checkbox on `change` and then redirect the browser to the download link. This way the download will trigger after you check the checkbox. How does this idea sound? I could help you with an example if you want.

Comment: Yes, much obliged to you. I edited my post with some basic code as I can see the decision for this question. Idea, if I get you right - I checked checkboxes, then click button, which send information about checked choices to django view, and then response from view create automatic downloading of, in my case, archive with the files identificated with the checkboxes choices.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what I mean:

**HTML:**

```
<form>
   <input type="checkbox" name="file" value="Document1">Document1<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="file" value="Document2">Document2<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="file" value="Document3">Document3
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
   if (this.checked) {
      var fileToDownload = this.getAttribute('value');
      $.ajax({
         url: '/server-side'
         data: { file: fileToDownload },
         success: function(downloadUrl) {
             window.redirect = downloadUrl;
         }
      });
  }
}
```

I haven't tested the code.

Comment: I added what I've tried to do, and compare with your solution. My trouble in this line 'success: function(downloadUrl) {window.redirect = downloadUrl;}'? I get the status code 200 but I do not have an automatic downloading file. And if I copy cURL to terminal and do 'cURL > output.zip', I get the file. This is a browser policy? and I must use window.redirect to avoid it? Thanks for help, Andrei

Comment: if you do a `console.log(downloadUrl)` what does it show?

Comment: There is the body of the downloaded file: 'row.xls>���... ' . But file doesn't downloaded

Comment: No no, you have to send the `URL` of the file not the content of the file. The redirect will trigger the download, (e.g. `/files/your-file.xls`)